# How to compile / clean / debug Android app?

Tags: android, debugging

I have added a some new codeline to a method, and when I am debugging Android app, that line will get skipped. `adapter2` line will not get executed. Why? There is a red cross beside that line. Anyway app works, all the other functionality are ok.

How? I have cleaned / recompiled the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Run or compile android app in android studio 
  From menu: Run->run'app' or Shift+F10

2.Debug android app in android studio 
  From menu: Run->Debug'app' or  Shift+F9

3.Clean android app in android studio 
  Build->Clean Project